# What type of segue should I be using for iOS text adventure app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

So I am currently in the process of building one of my first apps just something simple to practice with a text adventure. The basic premise is that I want to be able to explain the adventure to the user, present the story and at the end of each scrollable page give them options on how to progress the story each leading to different scenarios.

I realize I will need to be branching with many different views and segues and I am currently using the present modally segue when transitioning between scenes but I am having this concern that I may end up causing memory issues by doing this? From what I have understood in the past is that presenting the next page modally just throws it on top of all the other views is that correct?

Essentially I am just trying to find the best option for transitioning that would be the most efficient as I am still learning the basics. Eventually I will be segueing data to the next view as well so at the end of the adventure I can show the user their characteristic values based on their choices. Any thoughts?

P.S. I think the reason I chose present modally so far was it had the best transition I have found that makes me think of a book (Couldn't find a page flip transition)

Comment: If you want something that looks like a book, then use a UIPageViewController with the curl transition between pages. Modal segues are grossly overused, in my opinion, especially be new programmers. The main use for a modal should be some short term action where you need to get some info from the user before going back to the main flow of the app -- think of it as in interruption to the main flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on where you're presenting the modal. If you're presenting it from one main view controller, then the previous modal is dismissed.

If you were to use other methods, such as a navigation controller push, it would continuously build the view hierarchy and lead to a large memory footprint provided the user dug deep into the adventure.

> P.S. I think the reason I chose present modally so far was it had the best transition I have found that makes me think of a book (Couldn't find a page flip transition)

Personally, I would only use one view controller and have the view animate using the `transitionWithView` function. This would reduce your memory footprint greatly and provide interesting transitions for the user.

```
class func transitionWithView(_ view: UIView,
                 duration duration: NSTimeInterval,
                  options options: UIViewAnimationOptions,
               animations animations: () -> Void,
               completion completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

With this, you can provide a wide variety of animation transitions, and even randomize it so there is no idea which one is used and pretty cool functionality. Here are the transition constants

```
static var TransitionNone: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
static var TransitionFlipFromLeft: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
static var TransitionFlipFromRight: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
static var TransitionCurlUp: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
static var TransitionCurlDown: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
static var TransitionCrossDissolve: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
static var TransitionFlipFromTop: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
static var TransitionFlipFromBottom: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid memory issues, you can use `UIViewController`'s `-transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:` method to swap your controllers instead of a storyboard segue. You will call this method in a base view controller, which presents your visible view controllers, kind of like how a `UINavigationController` handles this.

Alternatively, consider using the `UIPageViewController` if you want something that looks like a book.